# Best way to insert into MS-Access Relational Database with Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado.net, ms-query

let's assume we have a Relational DB in MS-Access(image).[image]

Where We have 4 Tables and columns related to tables which are related to one another.

I know we can insert like:

```
INSERT INTO Project ( ProjectName, ProjectID, FK_Employee, FK_Department )
    SELECT 'Project1' AS Name, '99950' AS ID, Employee.ID, Department.ID
    FROM Department, Employee
    WHERE (((Employee.employeeName)=@employee) AND ((Department.DepartmentName)=@Dept));
```

1. But is there any better way to do it? I know we can `Select` with different types of Join. Is it make sense or is there a way to use Join with insertion?
2. I've faced a problem with this kind of query when the Foreign key is optional. What I mean is if I use this query for my VB/ADO.Net and if I send `DBNull.Value` it creates no new row or [image]

```
In precise.
```

3. Let's say I have saved no employee during project creation. So, my FK_Employee is Empty. Now, I want to insert a new Employee in the `Employee` table and also update the Foreign Key in `Project` table where `ProjectName` is 'Project1'. Is it possible to do it in one query? If it is not, how can I insert values in `Employee` Table and then read the Auto incremented ID and update it to `Project` Table in VB/ADO.Net? (Answer with C# is also okay).

I really am stuck here. If anyone knows the answer please help me to get rid of this situation. I really appreciate your kindness and help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to create a record in Projects that associates employee with department not in their Employee record, consider simply: `INSERT INTO Project(ProjectName, ProjectID, FK_Employee, FK_Department) VALUES('Project1', '99950', @employee, @Dept)`. As for question in 3 - no. Write code to accomplish these steps and when you have specific issue, post question.

Comment: Or instead of INSERT action to create record, use a bound form and do normal data entry.